# Material search view is taking whole height of screen

Tags: android, material-ui, material-design

I implemented a Material Search bar with Material Search View. The Material Search View is taking whole height of screen and my recycler view and Linear Layout with @id/llNoPlaces are not showing at all. I tried setting search view height to wrap content but it still didn't work. If there is anything to do in my Java/kotlin code please help me out, I don't know why it's happening. Can anyone help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar

                    android:id="@+id/searchBar"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:hint="Search Place" />

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:hint="Search Place"

                app:layout_anchor="@id/searchBar">

            </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/rvPlaces"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:visibility="gone"

            tools:visibility="visible"

            tools:listitem="@layout/item_happy_place"/>

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/llNoPlaces"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:gravity="center"

            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:visibility="visible"

            tools:visibility="gone">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="@string/no_places_title"

                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.HeadlineLarge"

                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="@string/no_places_description"

                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.TitleMedium"

                android:gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```